# we are unable to connect to the store

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I Have this Error When I try Realms in MCPE (android):

> we are unable to connect to the store. maybe check your connection?

I Have good Internet Connection...
What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some possibilities:

- The store might be down, perhaps  try again later
- It May be an internet connection issue, perhaps try restarting your router
- It May be a device issue, perhaps try restarting your device
- If you've never been able to successfully access the store, it could be down to restrictions on your network, those might need to be checked

Comment: what do you mean of last option?